# using Powershell to create GPOS

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I want to create a GPO using powershell however how would I know what values to use. For example say I want to create a GPO for opening notepad on startup, in the Group Policy Editor is straight forward enough to set this up, eg you locate the "Run Program on Log On" in the editor and configure as necessary.
How would you be able to to this in powershell? How would you know what syntax to use for this , is there a table of parameters somewhere I can refer to?

Comment: You may want to read up on [Running PowerShell Startup (Logon) Scripts Using GPO](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/)

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`Group-Policy` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: Forget about it, it's overcomplicated.